# matplotlib 2d data with floating values ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I keep struggling to get this to work like I want it too, but I can't seem to get it the right way. The issue is the following, I have some 2D data generated by a function of x, y that I'm trying to display on a pylab.figure.

The input data looks something like:

```
range1_labels = [0.002, 0.006, 0.010, 0.014, 0.018]
range2_labels = [10, 25, 80]
data_values = 2d array with dimensions (len(x_values), len(y_values))
```

From this using scipy's RectBivariateSpline I generate 600 x 600 values that I now want to display on a pylab.figure this generated data, but having values for x and y axis labels in those intervals. Attempts done so far:

```
    axes = figure.gca()
    img = axes.matshow(posteriori_data)
    axes.set_title("Interpolated values") 
    figure.colorbar(img)

    axes.set_yticks(range(len(range2_labels)), range2_labels)
    axes.set_xticks(range(len(range1_labels)), range1_labels)
```

This attempt still gives me labels [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500] for both axes.

Another thing I tries is:

```
    axes = figure.gca()
    img = axes.matshow(posteriori_data, extent=(min(range1_labels), max(range1_labels),
                                                min(range2_labels), max(range2_labels)),
                       aspect='auto')
    axes.set_title("Interpolated values") 
    figure.colorbar(img)
```

This seems to be closer to what I want. For the 'larger' axis the labels are generated properly and even on zoom it they are recomputed properly. So in the above example, labels for range2 appear as expected but no labels are generated for range1.

Any pointers?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your range is too small, and the tick locator is not coping with this gracefully.

Something like:

```
data = rand(600,600)
extent = [.002, .018, 10, 80]

ax = gca()
ax.matshow(data, extent=extent, aspect='auto')
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(5))

plt.draw()
```

will do what you want.

Digging into this a bit, what seems to be happening, you are using `matshow` which is a function tuned for displaying matrices.  The locator that it sets is a `MaxNLocator` which has a flag `integer` which forces it to put ticks only on integer values ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator)).  This makes sense if you are plotting a matrix.  In your case you are setting the extent to be less than 1 in range, thus you get not ticks.

An alternate solution is to use `imshow`

```
data = rand(600,600)
extent = [.002, .018, 10, 80]

ax = gca()
ax.imshow(data, extent=extent, aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')

plt.draw()
```

This is what `matshow` in fact does ([src](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py#L9028)), you can copy the features you want to keep from that implementation, and drop what you don't want.